# Select elements of a Matrix that are the same (or have certain relationship) and return their position and the element itself

Tags: matrix, filtering

I have a matrix and I want to pick the elements that are the same and return their positions and their values. It seems easy to me, but all I know is how to pick elements that satisfy certain conditions, but not in relation to other elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Union @@ list` finds all distinct elements in the matrix. Then we pass each element to `Position` which will tell us where a certain element exists. The result is a new list of this format: `{{value, {positions}},...}`.

```
list = RandomInteger[5, {10, 10}];
{#, Position[list, #]} & /@ Union @@ list
```

(`@@` is short for `Apply` and `/@` for `Map`, do ask if you have questions. Also you say that you are new to `Slot`, which I use (it's the same as `#`). `{#,func[#]} &` is just a function, where the first argument is `#`. So what `func[#] & /@ {1,2,3}` amounts to for example is `{func[1], func[2], func[3]}`.)

Comment: This solution will need to traverse the complete matrix once for every distinct element, thus it will have worse complexity than pairing up elements with pre-generated positions.  This one will run in time proportional to $n\times u$ where $u$ is the number of unique elements and $n$ is the total number of elements.  The GatherBy approach will run in $n \log u$ time.

Comment: @Szabolcs True, but it's very straightforward. Thanks for the comment though, it's important/useful information.

Comment: @Szabolcs Regarding the statement that any `Position`-based solution must have poor complexity, I think that if one writes it like this it might have the same complexity, even if it's slower: `Position[ReleaseHold@Thread[# - #2 &[Hold[list], Union @@ list]], 0]`

Comment: I agree that it's always good to show the most straightforward solution! (+1).  The code you show in the comment still has running time proportional to the number of distinct elements ($u$) because it needs to perform an operation for each element of `Union@@list`.  Having twice as many unique elements will make it twice as slow.  `GatherBy` will go through the list of all elements, and for each one it needs to decide whether it has seen it before or not.  For this it can use a more efficient method than just looping through all already seen elements (e.g. it could use binary search).

Comment: That said, the fastest solution is not always the best solution.  I usually start with the simplest code I can come up with and I only bother with performance if needed.  I don't like to sacrifice simplicity and readability if I'm not forced to ...

Answer (score 5):

The key function is `GatherBy`.  There are several ways to do it using this function.  Here's one:

```
mat = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5}]

positions = Tuples[Range /@ Dimensions[mat]]

elements = Flatten[mat]

result = GatherBy[Transpose[{elements, positions}], First]
```

You'll get sublists of items of the form {element, position}.  You can use `Part` and `All` to extract what you need.

---

If performance is key, use this variation on the same approach:

```
elements = Flatten[mat];
positions = Tuples[Range /@ Dimensions[mat]];
positionClasses = GatherBy[positions, elements[[#]] &];
```

Now the $i^\text{th}$ element of `positionClasses` will correspond to the $i^\text{th}$ element of `DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[mat]`.  This will be very fast, and possibly the fastest way unless you're willing to write lengthy and complex code.

This approach is limited by `GatherBy` and will run in time proportional to $n \log u$ where $n$ is the number of total elements in the matrix and $u$ is the number of distinct elements.  If you have lots of distinct elements, this will be *much* faster than any `Position`-based approach.

Comment: Thank you all. My matrix is 1594X1594 .
@Szabolcs :  strangely my mathematica had trouble performing your second solution ( kernel stopped responding for a while ! ) but your first solution was quite fast. 

 On the other hand I would like to this job with a limited accuracy, meaning I need to collect matrix elements that are for example 10^-5 or smaller apart ... your solutions must work if I can apply certain function that represents this criterion but I don't know how !

Comment: @Bahman If you can only rely on direct comparisons between elements, then neither of our solutions will work.  However, if you can come up with a function that can be used to group the elements into equivalence classes, then you can use this approach.  For example, you could `Round` every element to 0.0001 in `GatherBy`: `GatherBy[positions, Round[elements[[#]], 0.0001] &]`.  This is *not* the same as grouping together all those that are close!  But in certain situations it is a good alternative.

Comment: @Bahman If you need to rely on pairwise comparisons, your program will be much slower (but this won't matter if the matrix is not very big).  In that case use the second argument of `Gather` (not `GatherBy`) to specify the comparison.

Comment: Thank you. I think Round works perfectly here for me.

Comment: @Bahman The problem with Round is this: suppose you have a cluster of values that all lie between 1.45 and 1.55.  They're close to each other, all within 0.1.  If you now round to multiples of 1, you'll get two clusters instead of one: those greater than 1.5 and those smaller than 1.5.  This might not be desirable ...